# redux toolkit using older data in slice to minimize calls to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm fairly new to developing web apps, I started learning react + redux toolkit while using Django as a backend framework

to my point,

I was trying to minimize calls to the server by using a useEffect to check if the value of a specified selector is filled with data, so then I can use that data instead of calling the server again

now when I make the check

```
  useEffect(() => {
        flights.value.length <= 0 && dispatch(fetchFlights())
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])
```

it works when you first call the component
but after that, every time I open that component (whether I click on its link, or using a `navigate(-1)` to go back to that component) it won't display anything. I'll need to manually refresh the page for it to work correctly

this is for the component to render the data via a map function (works as it displays it when first calling it)

```
{!logged ? <Login /> : flights.loading ? <div>loading..</div> : flights.value.length > 0 && flights.value.map(...)}
```

now if i change the useEffect to this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchFlights())
    // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [])
```

basically without the data check, it works just fine

---

### I was wondering if there is a way to check for the data and have it displayed without a call to the server again

or hear your thoughts about calling the server again and again and maybe its just better that way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `redux-toolkit`, [`createApi`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi) feature is the best option. You can use the fetched data across your app without retrieving it multiple times or refresh the obtained data based on your needs (polling, caching, manual refetching, invalidating it after a certain time... )

```js
// Need to use the React-specific entry point to allow generating React hooks
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

// Define a service using a base URL and expected endpoints
export const fligthsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'flights',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://yourapi.com' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getFlights: builder.query({
      query: () => `/yourFlightsPath`,
    }),
  }),
})

// Export hooks for usage in function components, which are
// auto-generated based on the defined endpoints
export const { useGetFligthsQuery } = fligthsApi
```

The you can use it in your app like:

```js
export default function App() {
  // Even if this component is unmount, flights data will be cached
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetFligthsQuery()
  // render UI based on data and loading state
}
```

(This is a minimal example, complete working code needs importing the api in your store)